# What the difference between SendToAddress and (CreateRawTransaction + SignRawTrasaction + SendRawTransacrion) RPC methods?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core

Can I create, sign and broadcast transaction using `sendtoaddress` RPC method? And what the between `sendtoaddress` and (`createrawtransaction` + `signrawtransaction` + `sendrawtransaction`) RPC methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SendToAddress`is a convenience method that handles input selection and building the transaction for you. You don't get any control over which inputs are selected.

Using the `CreateRawTransaction + SignRawTrasaction + SendRawTransaction` methods, you can control the exact composition of your transaction, and set the inputs, outputs, and fee with a very high precision.